# Присвоить значение input

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
<input v-model="fio_child">

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return{
              data: {},
              fio_child: '',
           }
        },
    created(){
        this.get();
    },
    methods: {
        get(){
            axios.post('api/get').then(response => {
                this.data = response.data
            })
        },
    }
</script>
```

При выводе {{ data.fio_child }} показывает значение Alex

Как мне сразу присвоить значение input ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если правильно понял, можно так:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      data: {},
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.get();
  },
  methods: {
    get() {
      // при условии что приходит объект
      /*axios.post('api/get').then(response => {
          this.data = response.data
      })*/
      // для примера
      this.data = {
        fio_child: 'Alex',
        time: '8.09.2020'
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-if="data">
    <input v-model="data.fio_child">
    <hr> {{ data }}
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы сразу присваиваете fio_child: 'Alex', а мне нужно наоборот чтоб полученный результат присваивался, типа fio_child = data.fio_child, но к сожалению так не работает

Comment: немного непонятно, полученный результат это как? попробуйте объяснить, что у вас есть и что хотите получить

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, все работает!)

Comment: В примере я вывожу эти новые данные под полем `input`, они находятся в `this.data`